# WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not availab le (error: cuda unavailable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, spyder

Windows 7 32-bit
Spyder (Python 3.5)
Theano 0.9.0
Keras 2.0.2
Программа под Spyder'ом работает с gpu0 нормально.
Создал успешно при помощи инсталлятора pyinstaller Exe файл.
но при запуске exe выдано сообщение 
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not availab
le  (error: cuda unavailable)
что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум - стоит проверить следующее:

- установлена ли у пользователя CUDA
- установлен ли g++
- есть ли пути к nvcc и g++ в PATH
- установлен ли Windows SDK и есть ли пути к его хидерам в INCLUDE